# Uploading files on Google Sites - file cabinet, list page - doPost issues, unexpected error

Tags: google-apps-script

I had this script working, but a few weeks ago it suddenly stopped - I assumed I made some programming error but I've been unable to debug this for weeks.

I want a script on google sites that allows someone to upload a file (and some other information, like its name) and have the script attach it to a new file cabinet page and then update a list page with the new page's information.

I used parts of code from an old forum post, updating where I needed to. I am not opposed to rewriting if someone knows of a simpler way to do this.

Thanks!

EDIT: the problem seems to be in the doPost(e) function - after hitting submit, nothing happens, the gadget goes blank and I get the error message: "An unexpected error occurred."

```
function doGet(e){
  return getUi(e);
}

function getUi(e) {
  //create user interface for uploading information
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('File Upload');

  var form = app.createFormPanel().setId('form').setEncoding('multipart/form-data');

  //create grid to store information
  var formContent = app.createGrid().resize(6,2);

  formContent.setText(0,0,'File Name: ');
  var fileName = app.createTextBox().setName('fileName').setId('fileName');
  formContent.setWidget(0,1,fileName);

  var fileUpload = app.createFileUpload().setName('fileUpload').setId('fileUpload');
  formContent.setWidget(1,1,fileUpload);

  formContent.setWidget(2,0,app.createLabel('Short Description: '));
  var fileDescription = app.createTextBox().setName('fileDescription').setId('fileDescription');
  formContent.setWidget(2,1,fileDescription);

  formContent.setText(3,0,'Level: ');
  var level = app.createListBox().setName('level').setId('level').addItem('Introductory').addItem('Intermediate').addItem('Advanced');
  formContent.setWidget(3,1,level);

  formContent.setText(4,0,'Subject: ');
  var subject = app.createListBox().setName('subject').setId('subject').addItem('Fundamentals').addItem('Observing').addItem('Solar System').addItem('Stars').addItem('Stellar Evolution').addItem('Milky Way').addItem('Galaxies').addItem('Cosmology')
  formContent.setWidget(4,1,subject);

  var submitButton = app.createSubmitButton("Submit").setId("submitButton");
  formContent.setWidget(5,1,submitButton);
  //var handler = app.createServerHandler("pauseUi");
  //submitButton.addClickHandler(handler);

  form.add(formContent);
  app.add(form);

  var resultTextArea = app.createTextArea().setName("resultArea").setId("resultArea");
  resultTextArea.setVisibleLines(5);
  resultTextArea.setSize("80%","80%");
  app.add(resultTextArea);
  var ogga = 'good god';
  Logger.log(ogga);
  return app; 
}


function pauseUi(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  app.getElementById("file").setEnabled(false);
  app.getElementById("fileName").setEnabled(false);
  app.getElementById("fileDescription").setEnabled(false);
  app.getElementById("submitButton").setEnabled(false);
  app.getElementById("level").setEnabled(false);
  app.getElementById("subject").setEnabled(false);
  app.getElementById("resultArea").setEnabled(false);
  app.getElementById("resultArea").setText('Please wait...'); 
  return app;
}

function resetUi(app){
  app.getElementById("file").setEnabled(true);
  app.getElementById("fileName").setEnabled(true);
  app.getElementById("fileDescription").setEnabled(true);
  app.getElementById("submitButton").setEnabled(true);
  app.getElementById("level").setEnabled(true);
  app.getElementById("subject").setEnabled(true);
  app.getElementById("resultArea").setEnabled(true);
}

function doPost(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  Logger.log(e.parameter);
  //create new page for uploaded file
  var msg = createNewPage(e.parameter.fileName,e.parameter.fileUpload,e.parameter.fileDescription,e.parameter.level,e.parameter.subject);  
  //reset upload page
  resetUi(app);
  //notify user of success or failure
  app.getElementById("resultArea").setText(msg.join('\n'));
  return app;
}

function createNewPage(fileName,uploadedFile,fileDescription,level,subject){
  //site information
  var mysite = SitesApp.getSite("uw.edu","introductory-astronomy-clearinghouse");
  var labsPage = mysite.getChildByName("labs-exercises");
  Logger.log('url for lab page is: '+labsPage.getUrl());
  var msg = [];
  //create new page
  var page = findPage(fileName);
  if (page == null){
    var page = labsPage.createFileCabinetPage(fileName, normalizeName(fileName), '');
  }

  try{
    //add file to file cabinet
    var attachment = page.addHostedAttachment(uploadedFile);
    //see if already listed on list
    var listItem = getFileListItem(fileName);
    if (listItem == null) {
      var fileUrl = page.getUrl();
      var newValues = [repairUrlValue(fileUrl, fileName), fileDescription, level, subject];
      labsPage.addListItem(newValues);
    }
    msg.push('Refresh page to see your item added or edit your file at: '+fileUrl);
  } catch(e){
    msg.push('Failed to upload the '+ fileName +' attachment, possibly due to size constraints or time out issues.');
  }
  return msg; 
}

function getFileListItem(fileName){
  var mysite = SitesApp.getSite("uw.edu","introductory-astronomy-clearinghouse");
  var labPage = mysite.getChildByName("labs-exercises");

  var i = getListItemIndex(labPage,fileName,0);

  var items = labPage.getListItems();
  Logger.log('labPage list item'+items[i].getValueByIndex(0));
  return (i>-1)? labPage.getListItems()[i]:null;
}

//get the index of your item

function getListItemIndex(listPage,propOneValue,propOneIndex){
  //for column propOneIndex, returns index (row) that equals propOneValue, or -1.
  var listItems = listPage.getListItems();
  Logger.log('listItems '+listItems.length);
  var r = -1;
  for (var i = 0;i<listItems.length && r<0;i++){
    if ((listItems[i].getValueByIndex(propOneIndex) == propOneValue)){r = i;}
  }
  return r;
}



//repairs URL

function repairUrlValue(url,text){
  Logger.log('buildAnchor for'+text+'->'+url);
  var a = '<a href="'+url+'">"'+text+'</a>';
  Logger.log('...built '+a);
  return a;
}

//find name of page with normalized name

function findPage(name){
  var mysite = SitesApp.getSite("uw.edu","introductory-astronomy-clearinghouse");
  var parentPage = mysite.getChildByName("labs-exercises");
  var norm = normalizeName(name);

  var page = parentPage.getChildByName(norm);
  Logger.log('findPage '+page.getUrl());
  return page; 
}

//get size of attached file in KB

function getBlobSize(blob) {
  return Math.round(blob.getBytes().length/1024)+" KB"; 
}

//put the name into reasonable form

function normalizeName(header){
  var key = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < header.length; ++i){
    var letter = header[i];
    if (letter == " " && key.length > 0){
      key +='-';
      continue;
    }
    if (!isAlnum(letter)){
      continue;
    }
    if (key.length == 0 && isDigit(letter)){
      continue; //first character must be a letter
    }
    key += letter.toLowerCase();
  }
  Logger.log("normalizeName from '"+header+"' to '"+key+"'");
  return key;
}

/*
 i s A l n u m
Returns true if the character char is alphabetical, false otherwise
*/

function isAlnum(char){
  return char >= 'A' && char <= 'Z' ||
    char >='a' && char <= 'z' ||
    isDigit(char);
}

/* i s D i g i t
Returns true if the character is a digit, false otherwise.
*/

function isDigit(char){
  return char >='0' && char <= '9';
}
```

Comment: Put a try catch block around your code in doPost and see what error is caught.

Comment: Ok, did this, and got nothing. Logger.log works in the doGet portion, but doesn't produce anything in the doPost portion, as if it isn't even making it to the doPost. I googled around and found this: http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1384      but I don't have a "publish as service" option.

Comment: 'Publish as a service' is now called 'Deploy as a web app'. I guess you'd already have done this since you are showing up a UI inside doGet.

Answer (score 1):

Unexpected error occurs, most often, when you try to access a UI element by ID whose ID is not valid.

In your case, there is no widget such as

```
app.getElementById("file").setEnabled(false);
```